# Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement'

Tags: innertext

I have a problem, please help me : 
My error : Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement': The 'input' element does not support text insertion.
My code :

```
<div id="chatmessage">
                    <div id="fb-root"></div>
                    <script>
                    (function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                    </script>
                    <div style="position:fixed; z-index:9999999; right:10px; bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:-6px">
                      <input onclick="if (this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = '';this.innerText = ''; this.value = 'Chat với chúng tôi'; } else { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.innerText = ''; this.value = 'Chat với chúng tôi'; }" style="width:250px;color: ‪#‎333;font-size:16px;margin:0px;padding:7px;background-color: ‪#‎4172B0‬;border-radius: 6px;margin-right:-10px;margin-bottom:5px;" type="button" value="Chát với chúng tôi"/>
                        <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px inset;">
                            <div style="display: none;">
                                <div class="fb-page" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-height="300" data-hide-cover="false" data-href="<?=$fanpage?>" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false" data-small-header="true" data-tabs="messages" data-width="250" style="position:fixed; z-index:9999999; right:0px; bottom:46px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` elements cannot be the parent of any nodes, including text nodes.  By setting its `innerText` property, you're trying to create a text node to make as its child.

You may be interested in setting its `value` attribute instead, which is what shows in the input box.

Comment: How i can fix it ? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Remove all mentions of `this.innerText = '';` from the `onclick` attribute of your input element. I would also like to recommend that you separate your JavaScript and CSS from your HTML instead of making them attributes.

Comment: Thank for support, this error has not fix, thank kamoroso94 !